# why am i getting errors while attempting to build my signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I was just trying to create a signed APK and saw **[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qatec8l3XOI)** tutorial online. i followed all the steps exactly in the tutorial , but i still get the following error in the `messages` tab .

Error :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Silambu/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Silambu/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Silambu/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Silambu/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         Droidone:app:unspecified
```

if i don't generate a signed APK , android studio does't build my project and run it, so i really need to build a signed APK. So why am i getting this error and how do i solve this ?

**EDIT**: Build gradle files .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gautam.droidone"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
//        testPackageName "com.example.gautam.droidone.tests.MainActivityTest"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Other gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your build.gradle maybe you are duplicating a library.

Comment: @Santiago added the contents of build.gradle

Comment: the other build.gradle file is possible that are using mavenCentral() repository, add jcenter(), there are two build.gradle, the other is for repositories.

Comment: @Santiago , added the other gradle file too , does this have something to do with not installing the jdk right ?

Comment: Your JDK is not installed? This is very neccesary to compile the app, please install last version if you are using Android Studio 1.2.2 and above

Comment: @Santiago , as a matter of fact , it is installed http://i.imgur.com/sJkK2mF.jpg

Comment: Where do you have configured signingConfigs section on build.gradle file?

Comment: You have declared buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" on gradle.build, do you try with buildToolsVersion "22.2.0"?

Comment: Look with Android SDK Manager the version of Android Support Library on Extras section.